# while Using Extractor in riak for indexing getting error

Tags: riak, riak-search

after running command :-

```
curl -XPUT -H 'content-type: application/httpheader' 'http://localhost:8098/search/extract' --data-binary "@/home/cblap15/Desktop/google_packet.bin"
```

i am getting error as:-

```
<html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1>Internal Server Error</h1>The server encountered an error while processing this request:<br><pre>{error,
{error,undef,
    [{yz_httpheader_extractor,extract,
         [<<"\nGET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1\n\n">>],
         []},
     {yz_wm_extract,extract,2,[{file,"src/yz_wm_extract.erl"},{line,91}]},
     {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,
         [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,186}]},
     {webmachine_resource,do,3,
         [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,142}]},
     {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1,
         [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,48}]},
     {webmachine_decision_core,accept_helper,1,
         [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,616}]},
     {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1,
         [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,521}]},
     {webmachine_decision_core,handle_request,2,
         [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,33}]}]}}</pre><P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web server</ADDRESS></body></html>
```

How we resolve this??? while use of extractor in riak i am getting this.

Comment: my google_packet.bin file containing data :- 


GET http://www.google.com HTTP/1.1

Comment: that's not a valid HTTP header